# Pandas dataframe top users by amount within 2016

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with columns: customerId, amount, date the date range of this dataframe is: date: 1/1/2016 9/9/2017 I am trying to find the top 10,000 customers will be determined by the total amount of money they have spent in the year 2016; I was going to sort the amount column in descending order and then parse the date column by just 2016 using

```
mask = (df['date'] >= '1/1/2016') & (df['date'] <'1/1/2017')
```

there has to be a smarter way to do this, I am new to coding so any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try converting the column to datetime by:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#then filter by year
mask = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.year == 2016)
```

@A-Za-z's answer is more concise, but in case the column wasn't in datetime type already, you can convert it with `pd.to_datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .dt accessor given that the date column is pandas datetime. Otherwise convert it to datetime first

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df[df.date.dt.year == 2016]
```

Should give you the required rows. If you can post the sample dataset, it would be easier to test it